# Intragrate C++ fork in Java program

Tags: java, c++, fork

I've got a C++ library who use the `fork()` function to create sub-processes, and these processes communicate with each other with POSIX4 mechanisms (messages queues, real-time signals,...).

This library has to be integrated in a Java software. The integration team says, the `fork()` calls are forking the JVM. Is there a way to make the `fork()` works without forking the JVM ?

Comment: No, there are not. You need another approach, such as fork() and then exec() your programs, and communicate with those programs from your C++ library, or create a new program that is run separately from the JVM, and that you add communication over e.g. TCP/IP to, so you can easily communicate with that program from Java (without even needing to integrate the native C++ library with the JVM)

Comment: Instead of POSIX4 mechanisms and `fork()`, look at ZeroMQ / JeroMQ and use standalone (but coupled) processes?

Comment: Thanks, we will propose to the integration team to run the library as a stand alone program. @Eliott, the deadline is to close to change this now :s